# calling a class from another directory

Tags: java, android, android-ndk

I know this sounds a bit silly.. but im really confused about this:
[image]

I need to instanciate the FFTProcessor class to the main activity, or move it to the `com.example.audioconv` package (i tried moving it but i had problems loading the libraries).

The `FFTProcessor` class calls the native functions implemented in `in_waslos_kneo_libsimplefft_FFTProcessor.c`

Here is where i have to call the class:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
//---------------------------------------------------------variables declaration
File externalDir1=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File externalDir2=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File f1=new File(externalDir1.getAbsolutePath()+"/Test"+File.separator+"wav1.wav");
File f2=new File(externalDir2.getAbsolutePath()+"/Test"+File.separator+"wav2.wav");
//-----------------------------------load libraryv
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    try {
        //-------------------------read files
        float[]raw1=bytesToFloats(read(f1));
        float[]raw2=bytesToFloats(read(f2));
        float[] im1=new float[raw1.length];//----imaginary parts
        float[] im2=new float[raw2.length];//----

        for(int j=0;j<im1.length;j++)
        {
            im1[j]=0;
        }
        for(int k=0;k<im2.length;k++)
        {
            im2[k]=0;
        }
        int convhandle= FFTProcessor.createFastConvolutionContext(raw1.length, raw1, im1);
        FFTProcessor.performFastConvolution(convhandle, raw2, im2);
        //------------------------------------------------convolution log
        for (int i=0;i<raw2.length; i++)
            Log.i("convolution", "conv output   "+raw2+"  "+im2);
```

And in FFTProcessor class:

```
package in.waslos.kneo.libsimplefft;

public class FFTProcessor{
    public static final byte FFT_MODE_NORMAL  = 0;
    public static final byte FFT_MODE_INVERSE = 1;

public static final byte CPLX_TYPE_SP  = 0;
public static final byte CPLX_TYPE_DP  = 1;
public static final byte CPLX_TYPE_INT = 2;

static{
    System.loadLibrary("simplefft");
    System.loadLibrary("simplefft4j");
}

private static native int createFFTContext(int samples, byte mode, byte type);
private static native void destroyFFTContext(int handle);
....
```

any help?

Comment: are the methods static ?

Comment: Don't know about Android builds, but in Maven the Java code you use has to be under the `src` directory.

Comment: try importing, sth like maybe `jni.simplefft4j.*`?

Comment: Please don't post code in a screenshot.

Comment: @Blackbelt they are static..

Comment: You should import the class or refer to it explicitly in its current package.  Whatever you do, **do not** move the class which defines the native methods to a different package (which moving it to a different source sub-directory will require you to do), as if you do that, then you will have to modify the C code to match and recompile it, or else make a wrapper.

Comment: You java code should be under the src/ folder, not the jni/ folder.  Post the "package" line from the class you want to use, and people will be able to help you turn that into the corresponding import.

Comment: @ChrisStratton in FFTProcessor the package is package in.waslos.kneo.libsimplefft;

Comment: Then you want `import in.waslos.kneo.libsimplefft.FFTProcessor;`

Comment: I tried already :/ it not recognized as an import

Comment: are you aware that the FFTProcessor is not in your source path? which means that the IDE doesn't recognize that file as a java class, you can solve your problem by adding the full path to your class path, or if you are working with classes from a library, add the jar to the classpath

Answer (score 0):

you can just make another project how contain the second directory as source code and add it in the class path of your project.